# C pointer to 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-definition

So i'm creating a loop which can create a 3x3 board by setting the elements of a [3][3] array to enum EMPTY. While debugging, I can see that the program sets the first three elements of the array correctly before getting a memory access violation error, so I know this is a problem with the address of the second row of the array (when the 'i' variable turns from 0 to 1). How do I solve this? pointers are still a bit confusing to me tbh.

```
int main(void)
{
    int board[3][3] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int* p = &board;


    create_board(p);
    print_board(p);

    return 0;
}
void create_board(int *board)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
        {
            (&board)[i][k] = EMPTY;

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Didn't your compiler complain?? Give any warnings?

Comment: What do you think this does? `(&board)[i][k] = EMPTY;` I'd especially like to know your understanding of what the `&` does in that.

Comment: I know the & refers to the address, but tbh i was playing around with *board, (*board), board, and &board actually compiled, so i just stuck with that... :/

Comment: There's no need to `return` from a function returning `void`.

Comment: `&board` within `create_board` takes the address of the pointer, which is the local variable `board`, technically it is placed somewhere on the stack. This variable has an address completely unrelated to `board` variable in `main` function. If you do index operations on that pointer you end up anywhere else but where you wanted.

Comment: I would suggest to use a one-dimensional array of size 9 (as in 3 * 3) and do simple arithmetic `board[i * 3 + j]` to get a unique index on the board. That prevents a lot of the problems you seem to have with understanding how the memory is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many issues. Arrays in C do not hold any information about their sizes.

The easiest way is to use a pointer to the array:

```
void create_board(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*board)[rows])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {

        for (size_t k = 0; k < cols; ++k)
        {
            board[i][k] = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}
```

and main

```
int main(void)
{
    int board[3][3];
 
    create_board(3,3, board);
    print_board(3,3,board);
    return 0;
}
```

Similar way you can write `print_board` function:

```
void print_board(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*board)[rows])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < cols; ++k)
        {
            printf("[%zu][%zu] = %d\t", i, k, board[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally would prefer `create_board(sizeof(board), sizeof(*board), board);` so that we have magic numbers only on creating the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. The compiler should issue a message that there are used incompatible pointer types in this declaration

```
int* p = &board;
```

The initializing expression has the type `int ( * )[3][3]` while the initialized object has the type `int *`.

The function can be declared either like

```
void create_board( int ( *board )[3], size_t n )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {

        for (size_t k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
        {
            board[i][k] = EMPTY;

        }
    }
}
```

and called like

```
int ( *p )[3] = board;
create_board( p, 3 );
```

Or if your compiler supports variable length arrays then like

```
void create_board( size_t m, size_t n, int ( *board )[n] )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {

        for (size_t k = 0; k < n; ++k)
        {
            board[i][k] = EMPTY;

        }
    }
}
```

and called like

```
int ( *p )[3] = board;
create_board( 3, 3, p );
```

Comment: @0___________ I think the reason is the comment to your question.